# ADF Pipeline Expression Builder - Concat Parameters & functions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, expression

**I need help writing the correct expression for a REST API connection I´ve build in a ADF pipeline.**
I need to dynamiclly change the created_since and created_before values in the URL to be active based on todays date. I need to filter by the last 2 weeks.

I´m trying to acheive this by keeping the Base URL the same without these two values and then add a expression into the Relative URL to change these two filters.

the result should be something like this:

**API.API.co.uk/api/get-clients/campaigns? limit=100&offset={offset}&created_since=2023-08-18%2007%3A29%3A25&created_before=2023-08-17%2008%3A29%3A25**

this works as i´ve tested it outside of ADF however I need the values to change automatically and not be hard coded.

I´m using the Concat funcion to join up the two string parameters and the UTCnow functions available in the expression builder however it doesnt like it.

heres the expression I´ve got:

```
@concat(dataset().{created_before},formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),dataset().{created_since},formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-1),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

here´s a look at the two parameters I´ve set up.
[parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wjaW.png)

I´ve also tried a few different ways by adding variables directly into the base URL and then using query parameters and normal parameters to change the dates however I couldnt get these to work either. **is there a better way to do this??**

Answer (score 0):

> **API.API.co.uk/api/get-clients/campaigns? limit=100&offset={offset}&created_since=2023-08-18%2007%3A29%3A25&created_before=2023-08-17%2008%3A29%3A25**

To get the URL like that, follow the below approach.

First create the dataset parameters for the `created_since` and `created_before`.

[image]

Now, use these parameters in the URL. Here, for demo I am using your URL and I am using the dataset parameters in the Relative URL.

Change the Base and relative URL as per your requirement but use the parameters at the values of the dates by using string interpolation(`@{<dataset parameter>}`).

```
?limit=100&offset={offset}&created_since=@{dataset().created_since}%2007%3A29%3A25&created_before=@{dataset().created_before}%2008%3A29%3A25
```

[image]

Now, in the copy activity, it will ask the values for the dataset parameters. Here, use the utc functions to give the date.

Here, for demo I am giving the yesterday date for `created_before`

```
@adddays(utcNow(),-1,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

and today date for `created_before`.

```
@utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Change the dates as per your requirement.

[image]

Here, ignore that my copy activity failed because it's not a valid URL. But you can see in the error that I got the desired URL.

[image]

Comment: thanks. follow up question. do I need the "%2007%3A29%3A25" part of the below URL or just the dataset parameters?


?limit=100&offset={offset}&created_since=@{dataset().created_since}%2007%3A29%3A25&created_before=@{dataset().created_before}%2008%3A29%3A25

Comment: If '%2007%3A29%3A25' this is a static part of your URL, then you can use the above approach. If it is a dynamic part, you need to create dataset parameters for it as well.

Comment: okay thanks. It´ll have to be a dynamic part so I´ll remove this and just try with the "&created_since=@{dataset().created_since}" part

Comment: I´ve added it like you said but its saying its in the wrong format? I´ve added a screenshot of the new parameters i´ve set as per your screenshots

Rest call failed with client error, status code 400 BadRequest, please check your activity settings.
Request URL: https://abbotts.fastdox.co.uk/api/get-clients/campaigns?limit=100&offset=0&created_before=%7Bcreated_before%7D&created_since=%7Bcreated_since%7D.
Response: {"created_since":["The created since does not match the format Y-m-d H:i:s."],"created_before":["The created before does not match the format Y-m-d H:i:s."]}